# A nice question on basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am really Confused about this question:

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3), y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3 $ be linearly independent. 
Let 
$$\delta_1 =x_2y_3-y_2x_3$$ 
$$\delta_2 =x_1y_3-y_1x_3$$ 
$$\delta_3 =x_1y_2-y_1x_2$$ 
 If V is the span of $x,y$ then,

- $V=\{(u,v,w):\delta_1u-\delta_2v+\delta_3w=0\}$
- $V=\{(u,v,w):-\delta_1u+\delta_2v+\delta_3w=0\}$
- $V=\{(u,v,w):\delta_1u+\delta_2v-\delta_3w=0\}$
- $V=\{(u,v,w):\delta_1u+\delta_2v+\delta_3w=0\}$

What I have understood so far that all deltas are actually co-factors of the determinant.

\begin{vmatrix}
u & v & w  \\ 
x_1 &x_2&x_3 \\ 
y_1&y_2&y_3 \\ 
  \notag
\end{vmatrix}

So, since $\{u,v,w\}$ are independent so, 1st option is correct.

Am I correct?

Comment: You can simply write $(u,v,w)=c_1\cdot (x_1,x_2,x_3)+c_2\cdot (y_1,y_2,y_3)$ and then insert them inside the equations and then see which one is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is correct, since the expression $\delta_1u-\delta_2v+\delta_3w$ correctly expresses the determinant

$$\begin{vmatrix}
u & v & w  \\ 
x_1 &x_2&x_3 \\ 
y_1&y_2&y_3 \\ 
  \notag
\end{vmatrix}.$$

Since $x$ and $y$ are assumed to be linearly independent, a vector $(u,v,w)$ is in the plane spanned by $x$ and $y$ if and only if the above determinant is zero.

Comment: oh yes! thanks for pointing out my mistake